# Remote Desktop Connection from Windows 11 Home to Windows 11 Pro

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-11

Is it possible to do a Remote Desktop Connection from a PC with windows 11 Home Edition to a PC with windows 11 Pro Edition ?

I can't find Remote Desktop connection on Home Edition.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can remote desktop *from* Windows 11 Home *to* Windows 11 Pro.  Not the other way around.

The program/app in the Start menu is called "Remote Desktop Connection"

You can also just run `mstsc.exe`

Comment: There are 2 answers  here : the first says is Possible From Home to Pro but not vice versa , the second says is possible From Pro to Home  but not Vice versa. What is the TRUE ?????

Comment: @alex I read this quite clearly as running a client on Home connecting to the Remote Desktop service on Pro. (This is correct, too.)